# Idiomatic way to remove repetitive request method checking code

Tags: rest, api, go, web-applications, idioms

I am writing a web server for a REST API and I frequently find myself checking whether a request method has a certain value, otherwise responding with method not allowed error, for instance:

**route.go**

```
package engine

import "net/http"

// Route represent a web handler with optional middlewares
type Route struct {
    Logger  bool
    Handler http.Handler
}
```

**testroute.go**

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"

    "my/engine"
)

type TestRoute struct{}

...

func (tr TestRoute) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        tr.list(w, r)
    } else {
        engine.Respond(w, r, http.StatusMethodNotAllowed, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed))
    }
    return
}
```

As you can see, **testroute.go** contains an http.Handler, TestRoute, which has to check the request method before calling the according function, else responding with http.StatusMethodNotAllowed. Note that the Respond function merely responds with the error in JSON format, so its internals are not important. I would like to know whether the following solution is idiomatic and, if it is not, a possible solution for the situation. I create a file **handler.go** as part of the engine package:

```
package engine

import (
    "net/http"
)

type RouteHandler interface {
    Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
    Post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
    Put(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
    Patch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
    Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
}

type BaseRouteHandler struct {}

func methodNotAllowed(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    return Respond(w, r, http.StatusMethodNotAllowed, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed))
}

func (rh BaseRouteHandler) Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _ = methodNotAllowed(w, r)
}

func (rh BaseRouteHandler) Post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _ = methodNotAllowed(w, r)
}

func (rh BaseRouteHandler) Put(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _ = methodNotAllowed(w, r)
}

func (rh BaseRouteHandler) Patch(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _ = methodNotAllowed(w, r)
}

func (rh BaseRouteHandler) Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _ = methodNotAllowed(w, r)
}

func Handle(rh RouteHandler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
            rh.Get(w, r)
        case "POST":
            rh.Post(w, r)
        case "PUT":
            rh.Put(w, r)
        case "PATCH":
            rh.Patch(w, r)
        case "DELETE":
            rh.Delete(w, r)
        default:
            _ = methodNotAllowed(w, r)
    }
}
```

I then change **testroute.go** to this:

```
type TestRoute struct{
    engine.BaseRouteHandler
}

...

func (tr TestRoute) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    engine.Handle(tr, w, r)
    return
}

func (tr TestRoute) Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := "test route found! congrats"
    engine.Respond(w, r, http.StatusOK, data)
}
```

Note that I only overwrite the method needed for this endpoint and the rest of the methods will respond with an http.StatusMethodNotAllowed automatically.

Comment: Assuming this is abridged code: lgtm, provided you need all methods all the time.

Comment: Maybe consider use interface casting to see if a handler has a certain method and call that method accordingly. This way you don't need to have a base struct embeded.